# How to show number of matching entries next to crosstalk checkbox filter?

Tags: r, reactable, crosstalk

I'm using checkbox filters from [`crosstalk`](https://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/) to filter entries in a table made with [`reactable`](https://glin.github.io/reactable/index.html).

I need a simple way to get the checkboxes to show the number of corresponding entries next to them.

Here's a minimal example of a table with checkbox filters:

**Example.Rmd**

````markdown
---
title: "Filtering with crosstalk"
---

```{r}
library(reactable)
library(crosstalk)

data <- SharedData$new(iris)

filter_checkbox("species", "Species", data, ~Species)

reactable(data)
```
````

It spits out this:
[image: cross-talk checkboxes with the iris dataset]

I need the checkboxes to show the number of corresponding entries next to them, like this:

[image]

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: would an R-shiny solution be acceptable? or only Rmarkdown?

Comment: @Claudio, simpler solution is better in my use case so ideally without {shiny}

Answer (score 2):

You can create the desired category label as a column to the dataset itself, then pass the data to `SharedData$new()` and create `filter_checkbox` based on that newly created column. Then hide this newly created column in `reactable` using `colDef(show = FALSE)`.

````
---
title: "Filtering with crosstalk"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message=FALSE)
```

```{r}
# preparing the label into the data itself

library(dplyr)

iris_df <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(
    Species_label = paste0(Species, " (",n(), ")")
  ) %>% ungroup()
```

```{r}
library(reactable)
library(crosstalk)

data <- SharedData$new(iris_df)

filter_checkbox("species", "Species", data, ~Species_label)

reactable(data,
          columns = list(
            Species_label = colDef(show = FALSE)
          ))
```
````

---

[image: reactable with custom filter label]

---